# Multiple users connected to same Host Name (IP Address) via SSH. "ps U <env_name>" shows Process ID's of those connected. Can I message them somehow?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty

Question says it all. The situation: There are several SSH logins all logged in under the same username. The command "ps U wvsd" shows something like this:

```
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
1990 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@notty
1991 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server
3388 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@pts/0
3389 pts/0    Ss+    0:00 -ksh
5174 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@notty
5175 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server
5186 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@pts/2
5187 pts/2    Ss+    0:00 -ksh
5678 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@notty
5679 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server
7350 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@notty
7351 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server
8602 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@notty
8603 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server
8736 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@notty
8737 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server
8748 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@pts/6
8749 pts/6    Ss+    0:00 -ksh
10459 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@notty
10460 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server
11151 ?        S      0:00 sshd: wvsd@pts/4
11152 pts/4    Ss     0:00 -ksh
11337 pts/4    R+     0:00 ps U wvsd
```

I know the PID's of "sshd: wvsd@notty" are other users logged in. Using their PID, is there any way for me to send them a message?

This is on Linux SUSE 11 x64.

Thank you

Comment: Most of your connected clients are using sftp.  There is no terminal for sftp.  So there is no way to message them.  It looks like you have 7 sftp connections and 4 interactive sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `who` to get a list of users and their TTY's and then use `write` to send a message to that specific TTY:

```
% who -H
NAME     LINE         TIME         COMMENT
teun     pts/0        Dec  9 09:05 (my.hostname.tld)

% write teun pts/0
OHAI
```

And end the message using Ctrl-D.

Answer (score 1):

Good one Teun! I Didnt know that!

You can also use the wall command to message everyone:

```
wall <enter>
Hello everyone thats logged in!
<Ctrl-D>
```

And everyone that's logged in will get the message.